# How to add image in Navbar in react-materialize?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-design

I have the following code in ReactJS where I am using react-materialize for UI.

```
import {Logo} from './logo.png';
<Navbar brand='logo' right>
 <NavItem href='get-started.html'>Getting started</NavItem>
 <NavItem href='components.html'>Components</NavItem>
</Navbar>
```

How do I replace brand with an image? I tried the following:

- brand={Logo}
- src={Logo}

But it doesn't work. Is there a solution for this?

**Solved:**

Declare a variable with the HTML div as follows:

```
var Img = <img src={ImportedImage}/>
```

and further assign it to brand on the Navbar as follows:

```
<Navbar brand={Img} ...../>
```

The reason that `brand={Logo}` didn't work is that it wasn't an HTML image form and hence showed a random text on the web browser.

Comment: That should work. Or `brand={require('./logo.png')}` given that `logo.png` is in the same directory as the component.

Comment: No, it instead returns a long string which I presume is the address of the png in the react project.

Comment: Fixed. I made a variable `var Img = <img src={Logo}` and then assigned it to brand as `brand={Img}`. And it worked.